# Calculating limits of Trig Functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I'm currently practicing how to calculate the limit of trigonometric functions (without using L'Hospitaler though), and am stuck on problems with additions/subtractions in the denominator.
For example:

$$\lim_{x\to0}   \frac{1 − \cos 2x}{x^3 + 2x}$$

Where I multiply by:$$\frac{1 + \cos2x }{1 + \cos2x }$$To get:$$ \frac{1 - \cos^2 (2x)}{ 2\cos^2x (x^3 + 2x)}
= \frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2\cos^2x (x^3 + 2x)} $$

And get stuck here. . .

Or:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{ \sin x}{ x^2 - \pi^2}$$

Any hints, tips, and tricks welcome!
Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Wait are there 2 separate questions? Because where did that $\pi$ thing come from? If they're separate questions, probably best to make a second question to avoid confusion.

Comment: $$\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2\cos^2x (x^3 + 2x)} =\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos^2x (x^2 + 2)}. $$ Still stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use asymptotic relations to solve this limit. Namely, we know that:
$$1-\cos(2x)\sim 4x^2\,\,\, x\to 0$$
So, we have:
$$\lim_{x\to0}   \frac{1 − \cos 2x}{x^3 + 2x}\sim_\lim{x\to 0}\frac{4x^2}{x^3+2x}=\lim_{x\to}\frac{4x^2}{2x}=0$$
Because, when $x\to 0$, we can neglet $x^3$ in neglect to $2x$.

For te second limit, you can write:
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{ \sin x}{ x^2 - \pi^2}=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1}{x+\pi}\cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{x-\pi}$$
Let $t=x-\pi$. When $x\to \pi$, $t \to 0$, so:
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{ \sin x}{ x^2 - \pi^2}=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1}{x+\pi}\cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{x-\pi}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t+\pi)}{t}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$$

Comment: @miracle173: yeah. Sorry for the mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @NX27: if this answer has beens useful, let me know smashing that +1 or accepted answer buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{ \sin x}{ x^2-{\pi}^2}\\
=\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{ -\sin (x-\pi)}{ (x - \pi)(x + \pi)}$$